# RestKit Relationship Mapping by ID in URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

Assume I have an API at `users/1/items` that returns a list of `items` for the `user` with an ID of 1.

Assume the API response is as follows:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "description": "Some item"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that the response does not contain a `user_id` for relationship mapping. Is it possible in RestKit 0.20 to map to the `user_id` in the URL (in this case, 1)? If so, how? I could not find any mention of this in the docs/wiki.

Answer (score 5):

It is. You need to use the `RKRouter` class (which you would usually use with `RKObjectManager`). Once you're using routing and path patterns, you can use routing metadata in your mapping definitions.

[`RKRouter` docs](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKRouter.html)

[Routing configuration example](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit#configure-routing)

[How to use the meta data](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKObjectManager.html) (section 'Metadata Mapping')

[Additional metadata info](http://restkit.org/api/master/Classes/RKMappingOperation.html)

Comment: I must be blind. Taking a look now. Thanks!

Comment: The restkit.org links are broken

Answer (score 1):

You would actually accomplish this using what RestKit calls `Relationship Routes`.

Here is a short example:

```
RKRoute *aRoute = [RKRoute routeWithRelationshipName:@"user-items-relationship"
                              objectClass:User.class
                              pathPattern:@"users/:userid/items"
                                   method:RKRequestMethodGET];
```

Then you would get the items like this:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPathForRelationship:@"user-items-relationship"
                                                        ofObject:someUser
                                                      parameters:nil
                                                         success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result)
 {
     NSLog("I win");
 }
                                                         failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog("I lose");         
 }];
```