# Restkit edit inserting in coredata

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

i use restkit to consume a web service ,, but when i get data i want to add some other parameters, i searched and i found that i should implement function called willsave but i don't know the way

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:brandId,@"brandId",categoryId,@"categoryId", nil];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:nil path:@"/mywebservice" parameters:params success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

    [self getProductsList];

} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Comment: There is a lot of missing information here. describe your current managed object properties, the information you get from the WS, the parameters you wish to add and the data they should contain. `willSave` is a method of `NSManagedObject` you could override that is called when the context `save` method is invoked. unless you really know what you are doing and that this is the right solution for you, I advise you not to override it just yet.

Comment: so what you advice me to do ,, how i case modify the consumed object before inserting to the database ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RestKit Relationship Mapping by ID in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325026/restkit-relationship-mapping-by-id-in-url)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `willSave`, it depends what you want to do...

You can use the `success` block, iterate through the results provided in `mappingResult`, make changes and then save the main thread MOC to the persistent store.

`willSave` is a method on `NSManagedObject`. So, you would implement it on the managed object subclasses. This will result in changes being saved as part of the mapping process, but it's only really useful for derived values / time-stamping.

Comment: i have two arrays of objects downloaded from server , and i want to make the relation between them ,, [first , second] ,, so when consume first and insert it to database ,, i want when inserting second to tell him to point at object first ,, so i can get all second that relate to first

Comment: how are they related? can you not configure the mapping to do it?

Comment: the problem is i get every one of them separated from each other ,, category and products ,, i request category from a web service ,, then i request products using categoryId from another web service ,, but i want to link them in the database so i can select all products for specific category

Comment: So why didn't you ask about that in the question and show how you get each? you should be able to use the category id in the URL path to link them during the mapping...

Comment: product has object from category inside it ,, and category has list of products inside it ,, but this objects is null,, i want to add this object of category to products when inserting them so i can select

Comment: please update your question with the code for both mappings, response descriptors and JSON.