# modify consumed object before inserting in core data using restkit

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, restkit

I have a web service that returns category , and other web service that return products , note that i wanna make a relation between products and category, i'm using restkit to consume the web service and inserting it in core data ,, how to intercept the insertion and reimplement it , all i want is to add object from category in product before inserting it, so later i can select it

so i can add predicate like this

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category = %@ ",category];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate] ;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restkit edit inserting in coredata](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388350/restkit-edit-inserting-in-coredata)

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions, and consider marking some of your previous questions with correct answers.

Comment: i didn't get any answer yet , so i tried to post it again

Comment: You haven't added the requested information to your original question. This question has even less information...